# Jax-RS Content-Type priority

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs, java-ee-7

I've got a JavaEE application with a simple REST service where I want to support the content types `application/json` and `application/xml`. Everything works as expected when the client sends an `Accept` header with one of these content types in it.

When this header is missing though, I want to answer with **`application/json` as default**, but no matter what I've tried so far, `application/xml` will be used.

### Configuration Class

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
}
```

### Service Class

```
@Path("users")
public class UserResource {
    @Path("/{username}")
    @GET
    // The following variants didn't change the behaviour:
    // @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    // @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + ";q=0.5"})
    // @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";q=1.0", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + ";q=0.5"})
    // @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + ";qs=0.5"})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public User userDetails(@PathParam("username") final String username) {
        return new User();
    }
}
```

### (Generated) User Class

The class I'm returning is generated (maven-jaxb2-plugin) with JAXB annotations to support XML without further configuration:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "User", propOrder = {
    "username"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class User
    implements Serializable, Equals, HashCode
{
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1701L;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String username;
    // ...
}
```

### Further Information

- JavaEE 7
- Java 8
- Same behaviour with Glassfish 4.1 and Wildfly 9.0.1

Comment: Hmm, would contradict https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs002.htm#GILIK, "29.2.5.1 The @Produces Annotation": "...If both are equally acceptable, the former will be chosen because it occurs first...", wouldn't it? Just an observation, no help so far... Might even be a bug: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2564? Have you tried "qs=..." instead of "q=..." (see the linked bug report)? Contradicts https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2049 as well... Vote for bug...

Comment: @stef77 Thank you for the links, I've tried `;qs=0.5` but again no success, so it really does not work as [it should](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2049)

Comment: try switching the order to see what happens.   If that works, I would call it a bug as the library seems not to conform with the rfc